# What is the correct way to implement a massive hierarchical, geographical search for news?

Tags: search, geography

The company I work for is in the business of sending press releases. We want to make it possible for interested parties to search for press releases based on a number of criteria, the most important being location. For example, someone might search for all news sent to New York City, Massachusetts, or ZIP code 89134, sent from a governmental institution, under the topic of "traffic". Or whatever.

The problem is, we've sent, literally, hundreds of thousands of press releases. Searching is slow and complex. For example, a press release sent to Queens, NY should show up in the search I mentioned above even though it wasn't specifically sent to New York City, because Queens is a subset of New York City. We may also want to implement "and" and "or" and negation and text search to the query to create complex searches. These searches also have to be fast enough to function as dynamic RSS feeds.

I really don't know anything about search theory, or how it's properly done. The way we are getting by right now is using a data mart to store the locations the releases were sent to in a single table. However, because of the subset thing mentioned above, the data mart is gigantic with millions of rows. And we haven't even implemented cities yet, and there are about 50,000 cities in the United States, which will exponentially increase the size of the data mart by so much I'm afraid it just won't work anymore.

Anyway, I realize this is not a simple question and there won't be a "do this" answer. However, I'm hoping one of you can point me in the right direction where I can learn about how massive searches are done? Because I really know nothing about it. And such a search engine is turning out to be incredibly difficult to make. Thanks! I know there must be a way because if Google can search the entire internet we must be able to search our own database :-)

Answer (score 0):

Google can search the entire internet, *and* your data via a [Google Appliance](http://www.google.com/enterprise/search/gsa.html)!